# How to export HTML table in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs-1.5

I have created a simple table in HTML file. Now I need to make it exported in PDF or Excel or CSV format in Angular JS? Is there any easy way to do that?

Comment: Use a custom grid like UI-grid http://ui-grid.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example which exports html table, you can save as pdf, csv, xlsx and other supported formats by browser.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.exportData = function () {
        var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
            type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
        });
        saveAs(blob, "Report Example.xls");
    };

    $scope.items = [{
        name: "John Smith",
        email: "j.smith@example.com",
        dob: "1985-10-10"
    }, {
        name: "Jane Smith",
        email: "jane.smith@example.com",
        dob: "1988-12-22"
    }, {
        name: "Jan Smith",
        email: "jan.smith@example.com",
        dob: "2010-01-02"
    }, {
        name: "Jake Smith",
        email: "jake.smith@exmaple.com",
        dob: "2009-03-21"
    }, {
        name: "Josh Smith",
        email: "josh@example.com",
        dob: "2011-12-12"
    }, {
        name: "Jessie Smith",
        email: "jess@example.com",
        dob: "2004-10-12"
    }]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-click="exportData()">Export</button>
    <br />
    <div id="exportable">
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>DoB</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
                <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                <td>{{item.email}}</td>
                <td>{{item.dob | date:'MM/dd/yy'}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. this worked :)

Comment: Can we do this for pdf too?

Comment: you need `jsPdf` library inorder to save your `html` as `pdf`, here is the example http://plnkr.co/edit/5NonsdQ23nXwFchV01sB?p=preview

Comment: ok thanks.. I have one more query.. If I need to export few specific rows based on class name, can we do so using fileSaver.js?

Comment: yes all you have to do is change this target  `document.getElementById('exportable')` to your `document.getElementsByClassName('className')` but do prefer `Id` over `class` since it is used only once